# Opera: How to show bookmarks in upper panel?

Tags: opera, bookmarks

Is it possible to have bookmarks always displayed in upper panel, like it is in google chrome?

I can display bookmarks only in sidebar panel. I can add just icon "Bookmarks" to upper panel, but not particular bookmarks into it. 
Is it possible to achieve in Opera 12?

Comment: I don't think this question is appropriate here, please see the faq.

Answer (score 1):

Tried `View menu > Toolbars > Bookmark bar` ?

This is in any case a question that belongs on http://superuser.com, not stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

Select `Settings` on the left upper corner.

`Browser` -> `User interface` -> `Show the bookmarks bar`

[image]